# How to use sphinx with flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx

The documentation of my project relies mostly on sphinx generated autodoc. The purpose of the project is to provide a prediction service.

I wrap the service with flask. and it can be accessed through endpoint

```
localhost:5000/predict?...
```

I want to integrate the my documentation also to flask, so that it can be accessed through another endpoint in same application object like

```
localhost:5000/doc
```

How could I achieve this elegantly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphinx-doc generated files are static, so you just have to send statically.

Following the [`send_file`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file) documentation, it would be something like:

```
@app.route('/docs', defaults={'filename': 'index.html'})
@app.route('/docs/<path:filename>')
def documentation(filename):
    return flask.send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
        filename
    )
```